# Can we allow external users to download PDFs but prevent them from downloading Videos?

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, external-users

I am working on a new SharePoint online project, and we have this requirment:-

**External guests cannot download videos but they can download checklists like pdfs**

So is this possible?

Comment: If I can view a video I can download it using the dev tools network tab or a number of other methods, no matter what security you enable. I would tell the client it's a nonsensical requirement.

Comment: @DerekGusoff atleast not having the option Buit-in will be fine.. so is this possible using custom permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't natively specify permissions based on file type.

You could potentially put videos in one library and pdfs in another. Or in folders within a library and then set `View` permissions for the PDFs and `Restricted View` for the Videos.

Another option would be to design a Flow that sets the permissions when they are created in the library, but this seems complicated and potentially prone to error.

Comment: i tried to create a Restricted View permission, which mimic the Read permission, but without the ability to view version history, but this permission level did not allow the users to access the library, can you elaborate more on what type of permission will be inside the Restricted Read?